# What is this medal?

Tags: military, identification

[image: medal; ribbon has gold background narrow green strips]

I believe it’s British Army, though I am not sure from which era or conflict.

Comment: I suspect JayFor is wholly correct and and either, can you say what made you think it British?

Answer (score 15):

Using Google Lense to carry out a reverse image search suggests that this is a Dutch medal called the [Cross for the Four Day Marches](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_for_the_Four_Day_Marches). According to the [Identify Medals website](https://www.identifymedals.com/database/medals-by-period/pre-ww1-medals/the-cross-for-the-four-day-marches/):

> The Cross for the Four Day Marches (or Vierdaagsekruis in Dutch) is a Dutch decoration awarded for successful participation in the International Four Days Marches Nijmegen (Vierdaagse in Dutch) held annually at Nijmegen, The Netherlands.
>
> The full title of the decoration is the Cross for Marching Proficiency (Kruis Voor Betoonde Marsvaardigheid). It is more commonly referred to as the Vierdaagse Cross or Vierdaagsekruis.
>
> The cross was established in 1909 at the time of the first march, to award successful military participants of the Vierdaagse. Since 1910 it has been awarded to all participants who successfully complete all four days, both military and civilian.

Your medal has a V on one of the arms of the cross, not a K. Looking at the Gallery section of the [Dutch Wikipedia article](https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruis_voor_betoonde_marsvaardigheid), this seems to mean that your medal is the [pre-1959 version](https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruis_voor_betoonde_marsvaardigheid#/media/Bestand%3AKruis_voor_betoonde_marsvaardigheid_pre_1959.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

According to the U.S. Army (https://www.army.mil/article/268559/the_four_day_march) @Paul hennessey this is an international medal awarded to any uniformed member of an armed service that completes the 4 day march.